# Adafruit hid switch keyboard layout

Tags: adafruit, keyboard-layout, raspberry-pi-pico

That's probably a stranger question, but I built a little rubber ducky with a Raspberry pi pico. Now the problem is the keyboard layout is in us but I would like to change it to de (German) but don't know how to do it. The layout is saved as an Mpy file and I used adafruit for it. So the adafruit hid it or is there a better variant for it? I hope this was the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `raspi-config` available, run this at a terminal prompt:

`sudo raspi-config`

It should launch a configuration tool that includes localisation options, which would include keyboard layout.

Comment: `raspi-config` on a Raspberry Pi Pico, don't think so !

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, I will clarify that rubber ducky is a software that simulates keyboard input to computer. The basic layout for the input is US keyboard.

**You can find more layouts including installation guide here:** https://github.com/Neradoc/Circuitpython_Keyboard_Layouts